# 12 month rolling data from earliest invoice date - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

Seeking help with the following problem statement.

I/P Data Set:

```
customer id invoice date    item id invoice amount      Comment
1           10-Jan-2014     1       10                  Start of 12 month window - 10th Jan 2014 to 10th Jan 2015
1           20-Jan-2014     2       20                  Falls within 12 month window
1           21-Aug-2014     1       10                  Falls within 12 month window
1           31-Dec-2014     1       10                  Falls within 12 month window
1           20-Feb-2015     1       10                  Start of new 12 month window as this is post 10th Jan 2015
1           30-Mar-2016     1       10                  Start of new 12 month window as this is post 20th Feb 2016
```

Desired o/p
customer id invoice date    item id invoice amount  window  sum(amount where item id = 1)

```
1           10-Jan-2014     1       10              1       10
1           20-Jan-2014     2       20              1       0
1           21-Aug-2014     1       10              1       20
1           31-Dec-2014     1       10              1       30
1           20-Feb-2015     1       10              2       10
1           30-Mar-2016     1       10              3       10
```

I tried using the following query in Hive to achieve the above output but the challenge is in resetting the next window once we have crossed the 12 month mark. (Please refer to rows 5 and 6 in the input data set). The need is for these records to be considered as start of a new window.

Following Query Used:

```
SELECT SUM(if(item_id = 1, invoice_amount, 0)) OVER (
    PARTITION BY customer_id 
    ORDER BY invoice_date ASC 
    RANGE BETWEEN 31556926 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
) FROM INVOICE_DETAILS;`
```

Comment: (1) Does the 2nd window starts on 20-Feb-15 or on 10-Jan-15 (a year after 10-Jan-14)? (2) By all means, use `date` type or at least string in ISO format YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Hello Dudu (kindly excuse the date format, it was reformatted in excel). the second window should start from 20-Feb-2015 in the above scenario. So I need to sum the amounts for all invoices between 10-Jan-2014 to 10-Jan-2015 and then look at the next invoice (later than 10-Jan-2015) to determine the start of the next window (which in my case would be 20-Feb-2015)

Comment: Please tag the question only with relevant tags.